# Meaning of "to put a face on something"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

A pop star is about to get an abortion, and now she is being interviewed. she says the following sentence :

I am very excited about this opportunity **to put a face on** this important issue.

What's the meaning of "to put a face on"?

Comment: Is this that Bojack Horseman episode again?

Comment: I think it's sloppy phrasing. But what I think she means is some people don't really know much about abortion, and she wants ***her*** face to be the one they associate with this delicate subject. Making it a "personal" issue centred around people like her, rather than just something sociologists and academics discuss. Personally, I'd ignore the connection to the subject of abortion, and understand anything she says as *That's enough about that! Now let's talk about something really interesting! **Me!***

Comment: This is not a common phrase -- it's bad writing.

Comment: To put on a brave, etc. face on something, to put a face to some situation with a person. The pop star cannot be expected to speak well, right?

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20a%20human%20face%20on) has this definition:

> ***put a human face on***
> : to make (something) more appealing, easier to understand, or easier to care about by connecting it to an actual person
>
> "*The author puts a human face on the disease by interviewing people who have it.*"

The meaning is the same as "put a face on". In the case of this Bojack Horseman episode, the pop star couldn't say "put a *human* face on" because she is a bottlenose dolphin.